# join hints always improve query. what's going on?

Tags: t-sql

So, been doing t-sql-stuff for some time and just today I stumbeled upon a thing called "join hints". Never heard about them before but apereantly you can try tuning you querys with 'em. Read that this is supposed to be a last resort option if nothing else works.

Just for fun I tried this on some random querys with a random hint and the query always ran much, much faster?
Since alot of other threads proclaimed that you never should do this but instead try to fix your DB with statistics and stuff I have som questions I thought somebody might be able to answer.

Why not always use a random hint since it always improves your query?

And secondly, (I don't experience any problems but) what's wrong with my db? : D

Comment: Faster doesn't mean better. The cost-based optimizer also takes RAM and CPU load into account, so you might find it running one query fast because it got all the RAM. Imagine the same query running 10,000 times.

Comment: Can you take one of the queries that run "much faster" and provide XML actual execution plans for both versions?

Comment: I would be surprised if you actually managed to get a database where "random join hints always improve performance"

Answer (score 2):

> Why not always use a random hint since it always improves your query?

Because it does not always improve your query and if your data changes so the plan has to be adjusted accordingly you have basically limited the optimizers possibilities.

> And secondly, (I don't experience any problems but) what's wrong with my db?

Why do you think there is something wrong when you don't experience any problems?

I would guess it is not very big. Nothing wrong with that, only it does not matter so much what plans you get.